# Cron не выполняет команды

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node.js, cron

Я  могу использовать следующие команды:

```
start node-server
stop node-server
restart node-server
```

Таким образом я стартую в своей ноде-сервере, и она работает

Если я хочу перезагрузить ноду-сервер, тогда каждую минуту для этого выполняю команду `restart node-server`

мой кронтаб выглядит вот так

```
* * * * * restart node-server
```

но команда "restart node-server" не выполняется.

крон работает, линукс работает, node-server работает, запуск от рута по ssh.

Ничего другое не сломано, только cron

Есть какая-то ошибка логов у крона?

Или может быть оболочка из которой я выполняю команду рестарт ноде-серверу она видит команду рестарт, а оболочка нет

Comment: cron не сломан. Сломано понимание системы. Штука в том, что крон запускается с своим набором окружения. И то, что у вас restart находиться в переменной PATH - хорошо, а у крона - нет. Пропишите полный путь к этой команде и все будет работать (то есть, что то вида /usr/bin/restart node-server).

Comment: Для отладки попробуйте `/bin/date >>/tmp/date` команду, чтобы убедиться, что cron работает

Comment: О, а можно ли запускать крон в контексте окружения какого-то юзера? И пожалуйста сделайте ответ ответом) я поставлю его как лучший)

Answer (score 1):

Команда restart не была видна крону просто так, нужно просто прописать пути окружения прям в crontab вверху, и все будет работать

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin


* * * * * restart node-server
```